# pysnmp script giving error

Tags: python, pysnmp

I was trying too many things and hence I pasted the wrong code. Here is the code I am using

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
from pysnmp.smi import *


cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBind = cmdGen.nextCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('public', 1),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('junipertestrtr', 161)),
    (1,3,6,1,4,1,2636,5,1,1,2,1,1,1,13,0,1),

)

print errorIndication, errorStatus

for varBindTableRow in varBind:
    for name, val in varBindTableRow:
        print name, val
```

When I run this program, I get the error message 
"requestTimedOut 0"

However when I run
snmpwalk -c public -v 2c junipertestrtr 1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1
from the same computer's command line I get the right output

iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1.172.28.254.83.1.172.16.25.82 = Gauge32: 64902
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1.172.28.254.135.1.172.17.25.134 = Gauge32: 64902
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1.172.28.255.135.1.172.29.255.136 = Gauge32: 64861
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1.172.28.255.135.1.172.28.255.137 = Gauge32: 64861
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1.172.28.255.135.1.172.28.255.138 = Gauge32: 64861
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1.10.1.1.1.1.10.1.1.2 = Gauge32: 64810

what is wrong with my pysnmp and why am I getting a requestimedout error message?

Comment: You do not seem to be giving enough information - even the error line number does not seem to match. It would help to also provide the Python version you are using and the version of the libraries used (pysnmp).

Comment: Chances are you are using somewhat old release of pysnmp. Try to upgrade to the latest version. Or use old-style initialization like: cmdgen.CommunityData('my-snmp-agent', 'public')

Comment: @donatello I have added the correct code

Comment: @IlyaEtingof my code does use communitydata. How to check version of pysnmp? do you think that still mgiht be the issue?

Comment: Check the value of pysnmp.__version__ . If it's not defined, that's a really old pysnmp. The latest stable release is 4.2.4. Also, make sure you are using the cmdgen.CommunityData('my-snmp-manager', 'public') syntax.